# Trim letters from the end of a string

Tags: php, regex, string, trim

I am trying to write a function that will trim all the letters off the end of a string, upto the first number it hits.

I have child product names like, `item101S`, `item101xxx`, etc. and I want to output only the parent product name: `item101`.

Not sure if I should be using regular expressions or `!is_numeric()` or what.

Comment: If you are trying show us what you have and where are you stuck.

Comment: rtrim($product,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"); so I'd suggest that a regexp (or the sscanf() function) are better alternatives

Comment: can there be item101S1? If so, what are the rules then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
php > $s="item101xxx";
php > $pattern="/[^\d]*\d+/";
php > echo preg_match($pattern, $s, $m);
1
php > print_r($m);
Array
(
    [0] => item101
)
```

Comment: With this, `item101xxx101xxx` would become `item101` instead of `item101xxx101` (but with the examples provided by the OP, this works)

Comment: @bfrohs According to the OQ `item101xxx101xxx`is the child `xxx101xxx`of the item `item101` - so this is exactly what should happen

Answer (score 1):

The follwing will remove all letters (a-z and A-Z) from the end of the string

```
$temp = 'item404Ssss';
echo preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z]+$/', '', $temp);
```

Output is :

```
item404
```

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you?

```
$string = 'item101S';
$string = preg_replace('/(.+?)[a-z]+$/i','$1',$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to demonstrate using [sscanf()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php)

```
$data = array('item101S', 'item101xxx');

foreach($data as $datum) {
    list($parent,$number,$child) = sscanf($datum,'%[A-Za-z]%d%s');
    $parent = $parent.$number;
    echo $parent,' -> ',$child,PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: `list()` can be avoided by nominating parameters 3, 4, and 5 in the `sscanf()` call.  I can only imagine, though, that `rtrim()` performs better since it doesn't need to parse the whole string.  Also...  `%d` will drop potential leading zeros from a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
function rtrim_letters( $input )
{
    $output = preg_replace('/[a-z]+$/i', '', $input );

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: `$output` is a needless declaration / single-use variable.

Answer (score 0):

This function will remove anything, except digits after the last digit in the string. If there are no digits in the string it will remain unchanged.

```
function strtrim( $str ) {
   return preg_replace('/(.+?\d)[^\d]*$/i', '$1', $str);
}

echo strtrim("item101S"); // item101
echo strtrim("paosdkpasd"); // paosdkpasd
echo strtrim("23121asd"); // 23121
echo strtrim("1321345+"); // 1321345
```

[working example](http://codepad.org/WB0jDRUr)

Comment: The case-insensitive flag is useless.  The lazy quantifier needlessly slows down the regex engine. `[^\d]` is the same as `\D`.

Answer (score 0):

Because all of your sample strings contain numbers after the leading letters and because your strings do not contain multibyte characters, you can simply use `rtrim()` with two character ranges to remove trailing upper and lower case characters. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/oljXi))

```
$v = rtrim($v, 'a..zA..Z')
```

If your string only contained letters, this technique would create an empty string -- but that doesn't appear to be possible for your application.