# Remove last character from string if last character contain number in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

I have an array variable which contain values like this:

```
$items = array(
 "tbFrench",
 "eaItaly1",
 "discount21",
 "kkMM5",
 "NbndA",
 "fcMNSS334"
);
```

i nedd to remove last character of string from this array values if the last character contain number, for example:

```
$newItems = array();
foreach($items as $item){
  $newItems[] = $this->removeLastCharacter($item);
}
print_r($newItems);
....
function removeLastCharacter($string){
 // ????
}
```

i want the result to look like this when i `print_r` the `$newItems` variable:

```
Array ( [0] => tbFrench [1] => eaItaly [2] => discount2 [3] => kkMM [4] => NbndA [5] => fcMNSS33 )
```

Comment: Related: [Trim letters from the end of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9006969/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regular expressions to remove the last digit.

```
function removeLastCharacter($string){
    return preg_replace('[\d$]', '', $string);
}
```

`\d` matches every digit and `$` references the end of the string. So this will only replace the last character if it is a digit at the end.

Comment: `\d+$` is a better pattern, because he wants to remove a number, not a digit.

Comment: If you want to remove every digit at the end this would be correct. But the examples of the creator are showing that this is not wanted in this case.

Comment: The question is how to remove a number, not a digit. It's a difference. Just saying.

Comment: `the last character contain number` - Just saying. And with the examples provided it is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a RegEx replacement over all the items in an array by simply providing the array as the subject, like so:

```
$items = preg_replace('/^d$/', '', $items);
```

There's no need to put it into a function at all - `print_r($items)` outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => tbFrench
    [1] => eaItaly
    [2] => discount2
    [3] => kkMM
    [4] => NbndA
    [5] => fcMNSS33
)
```

If you want to replace *all* trailing digits you can use `/^\d+$/`

Comment: Unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Remedied... @emix

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with below code if it solve your problem

```
$items = array(
 "tbFrench",
 "eaItaly1",
 "discount21",
 "kkMM5",
 "NbndA",
 "fcMNSS334"
);

$newArr=array();
foreach($items as $item){
     $data = preg_replace('[\d$]','',$item);
     array_push($newArr,$data);
}

print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply?

```
print_r( preg_replace( '/\d+$/', "", $items ) ); // preg_replace accepts an array as argument, pass yours directly, no need for a loop.
```

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => tbFrench
    [1] => eaItaly
    [2] => discount
    [3] => kkMM
    [4] => NbndA
    [5] => fcMNSS
)
```

---

Regex Explanation:

```
\d+ — matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$ — asserts position at the end of a line
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a quick trick using rtrim.

```
$result =  rtrim($str,"0..9");
```

second argument is a range using 2 dots ".."

You are done !!!